# CKEDITOR: how to programmatically test if the editor is in inline mode

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Is there a way to test (via javascript, after that the instances of CkEditor are all ready) if an instance of CkEditor is working in [inline mode](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline) or not?

Answer (score 2):

Use `CKEDITOR.instances.yourInstance.editable().isInline()`. Also see [official API docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-isInline).

**Note #1**: Never check `getAttribute('contenteditable') == 'true'` because if you call [`yourInstance.setReadOnly()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setReadOnly) the assertion will fail. Editable element has `contenteditable="false"` in read-only mode but it still may be inline.

**Note #2**: Another reason against `getAttribute( 'contenteditable' )`:

```
// Since CKEditor 4.2 is possible to make inline instance out of <textarea>.
var editor = CKEDITOR.inline( 'article-body' );

editor.element.getName()    
>> "textarea" // In such case, editor.element refers to <textarea>.

editor.element.getAttribute( 'contenteditable' )    
>> null // Textarea (editor.element) is never contenteditable.
```

Comment: Make sure that you check it on `instanceReady` event in the callback (`editor.on( 'instanceReady', callback );`). I bet the problem is that you check it too early before editor is fully initialized, which happens asynchronously. Or... post some more code ;)

Comment: I check it in Firebug, so I'm reasonably sure that the editor instance is ready

Comment: So... maybe you check the wrong instance? Or you refer to a non-existent instance? Some name conflict? Use jsFiddle to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score -2):

I have debugged the DEMO at the http://ckeditor.com/demo#inline

And found this way.

```
var ckeditor_instance_el = CKEDITOR.instances['inline-sampleTitle'].element.$;
if(ckeditor_instance_el.getAttribute('contenteditable') == 'true')
    alert('IT\'S AN INLINE EDITOR!!');
```

Try it.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but this is not a good solution. See: my answer.

Comment: This answer isn't correct, because it's also possible that an element with contenteditable="true" has a not inline editor instance